# How can i find the following probabilities?

Tags: probability

Let $X$  be binomially distributed with $n = 60$ and $p = 0.4$. Now i have to compute

(a)$P(20\leq X$ or $X\geq40)$

(b)$P(20\leq X$ and $X\geq10)$

i know $P(x\leq X)=\sum_{k=x}^{60}\binom{60}{k}(0.4)^k(0.6)^{60-k}$

But i don't know how to compute the probability when it includes `or` `and`.

How can i compute (a) and (b)?

Comment: a) or is the union operator on sets and for b), and is the intersection operator on sets

Comment: @ChristopherErnst Do i need to do this as (a)$P(20\leq X$ or $X\geq40)=P(20\leq X)+P(X\geq40)$ and

(b)$P(20\leq X$ and $X\geq10)=P(20\leq X)\times P(X\geq10) $ ?

Comment: or and and are not additive or mutliplicative in that sense.  See the answers.

Comment: @ChristopherErnst I have understood my given problem but could you please tell me when do we apply `or` & `and` as `additive & multiplicative`?

Comment: "Or" is the union operator on sets.  So if A={1,3,4,5,6} and B={2,3,4,7,8}, then $A\cup{B}$ is essentially "an element is in set A OR in set B", and would be the set $A\cup{B}=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$.  IN contrast, "And" is the intersection operator and is $A\cap{B}$ which means "an element is in set A AND in set B" and would be the set $A\cap{B}=\{3,4\}$.

Comment: So in your case in part a, $X\ge{20}$ or $X\ge{40}$ means we combine the two sets and use the whole, which implies that simply $X\ge{20}$.  In part B, $X\ge{10}$ and $X\ge{20}$ so this means we intersect the two sets, which implies simply $X\ge{20}$.  As @AndreNicolas said in his answer, you get two for one!!  With probability, you should have an elementary understanding of set theory and the operations involved like "union (or)", "intersection (and)", and others (symmetric difference, de Morgan's laws, etc.).

Comment: @ChristopherErnst Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints**:

(a) Draw a number line of possible values for $x$. What do you see?

*More hints:*

> [image: Number line]
>  Note that we see that the stated condition is the same as finding $P(X \ge 20)$. Simply plug into the formula.

(b) Draw another number line. Note that this time it says "and", so you have to find where **both** (not one) of the conditions are satisfied.

*More hints:*

> Drawing the number line, we see that the conditions are **both** true whenever $X \ge 20$, so we just find that probability.

Answer (score 3):

(a) This is true precisely if $X\ge 20$.

(b) This is true precisely if $X\ge 20$.

So you got a two for one deal!

For (a), the condition $X\ge 40$ is automatically fulfilled if $X\ge 20$. So if you will be happy if $X\ge 20$ **or** $X\ge 40$, you will be happy precisely if $X\ge 20$.

For (b),  if you will be happy if **both** conditions hold, your condition for happiness is $X\ge 20$.

**Remark:** Please note that if the inequality signs were not indicated correctly, the analysis changes.

I do not know whether you are expected to use software to find the required sum "exactly," or whether you are expected to use the normal approximation to the binomial.

Comment: I am using software `R` for getting the sum. Thank you very much.

Comment: Many courses do that. Steep learning curve, but a great tool. Price is right too!