# Problem with Binomial Distribution P(20 ≤ X and X ≥ 10)

Tags: probability-theory, binomial-distribution

**This is a question from "Applied Statistics for Bioinformatics using R" by Wim P. Krijnen**

*Let X be binomially distributed with n = 60 and p = 0.4

(a) P(20 ≤ X or X ≥ 40)

(b) P(20 ≤ X and X ≥ 10)*
I'm using RStudio for this

For (a), I can get it with P(X ≥ 20) as it fulfils the 'or' condition, which is either
P(X ≥ 20) OR P(X ≥ 40):

P(X ≥ 20) = 0.8830403

But for (b), from my understanding, only P(X ≥ 20) fulfil the 'and' condition of
P(X ≥ 10) AND P(X ≥ 20)

However, the answer from the book is P(X ≥ 10) = 0.999975

Can anybody explain this?

Original question:

1. Binomial Let X be binomially distributed with n = 60 and p = 0.4.  
   Compute the following. 
   (a) P(X = 24), P(X ≤ 24), and P(X ≥ 30).
   (b) P(20 ≤ X ≤ 30), P(20 ≤ X).
   **(c) P(20 ≤ X or X ≥ 40), and P(20 ≤ X and X ≥ 10).**
   (d) Compute the mean and standard deviation of X.
   (e) The quantiles x0.025, x0.5, and x0.975.

Answer from the book:

1. Binomial 
   (a) P(X = 24) = 0.1046692, P(X ≤ 24) = 0.5557756, and P(X ≥ 30) = 0.0746237. 
   (b) P(20 ≤ X ≤ 30) = 0.83856, P(20 ≤ X) = 0.8830403. 
   **(c) P(20 ≤ XorX ≥ 40) = 0.8830403, and P(20 ≤ XandX ≥ 10) = 0.999975.** 
   (d) E(X) = 24, var(X) = 3.794733 Use: sqrt(60 * 0.4 *0.6) 
   (e) x0.025 = 17, x0.5 = 24, and x0.975 = 32.

Update: 
[How can i find the following probabilities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435731/how-can-i-find-the-following-probabilities)

This link suggests using P(X ≥ 20), but the two answers here are suggesting P(X ≥ 10), which might be the more accurate idea?

Comment: Please present the problem, word for word, in the exact wording that it was originally presented to you.

Comment: Hi I've added the original question, thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i find the following probabilities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435731/how-can-i-find-the-following-probabilities)

Comment: @AnneBauval Good catch; my blindness.  I therefore deleted my answer.

Comment: @AnneBauval hi, but I've asked most of my coursemates, and they go with the P(X ≥ 10), while my lecturer is too busy to entertain me, so I'm wondering what is the correct answer, I'm prone to P(X ≥ 20) but seems I'm the only one with this answer

Comment: Your coursemates probably looked into the book, which gives a wrong answer. Better trust yourself (and the duplicate).

Comment: Only *your* answer is correct.

Comment: While I did delete my answer due to several inconsistencies, note that the relevance of "and" = "$\cap$" are for us to simplify english definitions, instead of writing "intersection of" every now and then, but it should be kept to that "$\cap$" = "intersection of" strictly. There is no place that _definitely_ states "and" = "$\cap$", rather webs like wiki, brilliant and encyclopaedia often state "$\cap$" = "intersection of" because thats its mathematical definition.

Comment: More precisely, as explain with more details in my last comment to Unexpected Confusion's (now deleted) answer, the nuance between $\text{and}$ and $\cap$ is that they are used to denote the same event, but not with the same syntax: the set $(X\in A\text{ and }X\in B)$ is equal to $(X\in A)\cap(X\in B).$